# Adding reference to picture in SPD2007 workflow email

Tags: image

I am trying to add an image to my custom email to be sent through a workflow in SPD2007. The below works in every html test i have tried, except it doesnt work when the email is received for some reason.
Maybe someone can guide me on how to resolve this?

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/05/CEVA_Logistics_logo.svg/268px-CEVA_Logistics_logo.svg.png">


<img src="http://ceva.log-net.com/ceva.jpg">


<img src="http://sspcevamysite.logistics.corp/personal/hayekn/Disputes/Workflow%20Images/CEVA%20Logo.jpg">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt work when the email is received"? Is there img tags in the email body? Is your email client configured to dounload images in emails?

Comment: Hi. It makes sense, i think the issue is with the email client. Although my outlook is configured to read emails as "HTML", the images dont appear in outlook but instead an error box does. I'm sure its something stupid but i cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Look for image downloads settings in outlook: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/unblock-image-downloads-in-outlook-HP001085952.aspx

Comment: that answered my question and solved my problem. However i am just wondering will the same apply to anyone else receiving this? Thanks again for your  time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the email client (Outlook) is not configured to download images in emails. The solution: on each users's client enable image downloading.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/unblock-image-downloads-in-outlook-HP001085952.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciated your guidance :)